# How can I use a box-shadow on an element that has background-size:contain?

Tags: html, css

I have a div of fixed size, that has a background-image inside of it, and I use background-size: contain to size the image to fit inside of it. Where I am having trouble is trying to understand how to get a drop shadow that is aligned with the resized image, rather than the div as a whole.

e.g

```
    #picture-container {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: url('image.png') no-repeat center;
        background-size: contain;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - box-shadow, according to the spec, applies to the div. Attempted workarounds include putting an absolutely positioned img element inside your div (relatively position), setting the img to a max-width of 100% and putting the box shadow on the img tag.

Awesomely unsemantic JS fiddle attached that mimics what you are trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/VbFfL/1/

```
<div id="div2">
    <span><span><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/200"></span></span>
</div>
```

Border was added so you could see the outline of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Add `img` to `div` and then apply shadow to it.

HTML:

```
<div id="picture-container">
    <img id="image" src="http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Samsung-Galaxy-Gear-6-colors-side-640x361.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#picture-container {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: red; 
    }
#image
{
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
}
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQNqh/).

Comment: Doesn't mimic background-size: contain with background-position: center;

Answer (score 0):

We can add an extra div around the image with a class say `.picture-container`. By adding `display: flex` to it, we can easily centre the image inside it using justify-content and align-items. Then, we can add `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%` to the image. This will make the image to behave like `background-size: contain` and the shadow will follow the image properly.
Here is an example solution -

```css
.picture-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.picture-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200">
</div>

<div class="picture-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1000">
</div>

<div class="picture-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
</div>
```